# How to make NavHost acknoledge the navigation modules?

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, composable

In my Android app, which is a monolith architecture, I am trying to split the navigation on several modules, and I use this approach:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AppTheme {
                MainNavGraph()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then in MainNavGraph I load the modular navigations:

```
@Composable
fun MainNavGraph() {
    NavHost(
        startDestination = "start
    ) {
        firstNavGraph()
        secondNavGraph()
    }
}
```

then the modules look like this:

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.firstNavGraph() {
    ...
    composable('signup') {
        SignupScreen()
    }
    ...
}
```

and I would do this for `secondNavGraph`and all other nav graphs. Each fun NavGraphBuilder.() declaration is on a different module. The following errors occur. If I leave `NavGraphBuilder.firstNavGraph()` without the `@Composable` annotation I get

```
Functions which invoke @Composable functions must be marked with the @Composable annotation
```

and if I add the  `@Composable` annotation I get

```
@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function
```

How can I make the MainNavGraph accept those composables? And what other approach is there? My goal is to have a single NavHost inside the main app module and a separate nav graph for each feature(module) and use them all inside the NavHost.

Answer (score 0):

You've written:

```
@Composable
fun NavGraphBuilder.firstNavGraphModule() {
```

But the navigation graph is not built as part of composition - you don't need the `@Composable` annotation. As per the [Type safety in the Kotlin DSL and Navigation Compose guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/design/type-safety#split-navigation), that annotation is not necessary.

Comment: When I do that, it tells me that "Functions which invoke Composable functions must be marked with the @Composable annotation". The only way to make it work is to write the composable() {} directly inside the NavHost, but over time that will lead to a very big file. And I am using modules for my app, so I need every module to have it's own nav graph.

Comment: As per the doc I linked, splitting it into multiple files is absolutely supported. The `NavGraphBuilder` extension code you've posted does not contain any composable functions in it. `navigation` and `composable` are part of the Navigation Kotlin DSL and not composable functions.

Comment: I updated the code to show my setup as it is on my app. I followed the documentation in your link, but the same issues keep happening.

Comment: You still don't have any composables functions in the code you've included in your question.

Comment: SignupScreen is a composable.

Comment: I fixed it. inside the NavGraphBuilder.firstNavGraph() and before declaring composable('signup'), I had some variable declarations for some viewmodels that I was distributing to the composable() UI function through props. but I moved them inside the respective functions and it worked.